Getting DB connection errors while executing jmeter script
Currently, I am working on one load testing project where I need to execute jmeter script with 50000 users load. I have successfully executed the script till 30000 employees but after that I started receiving errors.
When I checked logged file, I got this this two below error which causing failure of my script during 50000 users load execution:



Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException
Login with User,Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException,"Number of samples in transaction : 8, number of failing samples : 1",Mobile Sign In- Mark attendance script 1-1110,,false,,10309,7144,3133,3133,null,0,57200,17




Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP response message: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 1",Mobile Sign In- Mark attendance script 1-3059,,false,,2544,0,3136,3136,null,0,5557,1
1723044354152,1,524 - /v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog (),Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP response message: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect,

To resolve this error, I have increased the database connection rate from 2000 to 5000 and checked again but I obtained same above two errors in log file of jmeter.
Eventhough, I have added this line in jmeter.properties file " httpclient.socket.localport=50000-51000" but still I am getting the error.
Can somebody help me to solve this ?



You either need to tune your operating system where JMeter is running and increase the number of ephemeral ports or get another load generator machine and run JMeter in distributed mode, i.e. 25000 users from each machine.
